# html5 canvas drawImage scaling makes result blurry

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html2canvas, drawimage

A couple of questions related to mine have been asked here, but still I am struggling.

I use html2canvas to make a canvas of certain parts of my webapp. Here I have the first question: the [documentation](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/configuration) gives a number of options (width, height, scale) which give the impression that they are intended to manipulate the size of the resulting image. I would like to reduce the size of the result, compared to the original div. However, whatever I do, I don't get it. If I set width / height smaller than the original div, it simply takes only part of the div (it basically crops). And scale seems to work on the ratio between canvas width/height and canvas css style width/height. It does not really scale down contents from the original size onto a smaller canvas.

Well, I could live with that and go forward with the resulting canvas at same size as original div, since there exist another good option for scaling of images on client side. 
I try to redraw the canvas on a smaller one, using drawImage with proper context.width, context.height and context.scale.It works but whatever I try, the endresult is rather blurry. Note that I am DOWNscaling (not even UPscaling) simple images, not high-res pictures. A screenshot of the result:
[On top the original div, just below that the unscaled result after html2canvas and on the right the down-scaled after:
 ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, width, height);](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkFjF.png)

My javascript:

```
function init() {
$('#testBtn').on('click', function(){proces();});
}

function proces() {
var testElem = document.getElementById("container");
var options = {
    //I could play here with width, height and scale

};

html2canvas(testElem, options).then(function(canvas) {
    canvas.id = "resultCanvas";
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    var width = canvas.width;
    var height = canvas.height;
    var scale = 0.5 / 1.25;
    console.log(width, height)

    //var scaledCanvas = document.getElementById("testScaledCanvas");
    var scaledCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    scaledCanvas.id = "testScaledCanvas";
    scaledCanvas.height = scale * height;
    scaledCanvas.width = scale * width;

    var ctx = scaledCanvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.scale(scale, scale);
    ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    ctx.msImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;


    //Draw the scaled canvas
    ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, width, height);

    document.body.appendChild(scaledCanvas);
});
}
```

So to summarize, downscaling a canvas results in blurry images. And I fail to get html2canvas to properly squeeze a div on a smaller canvas. It only crops.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Mark

Comment: Output is browser dependent.  `imageSmoothingEnabled = false` is ignored by Firefox when downscaling.